# Do F# Query Expressions have same performance as Native SQL?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

F# Query expression examples I notice look as though they grab the entire contents of a table before doing a computation. This seems less efficient than native SQL. Or should the performance be the same.

```
// A query expression.
let query1 =
    query {
        for customer in db.Customers do
            select customer
    }
```

Comment: The corresponding SQL would also be a `SELECT * FROM customers`, so I can't see a difference in grabbing the entire table...?

Comment: I was just copy and pasting an example from the web. But lets say we had a 10 million record table, and we wanted to get the most recently added entry. Does F# retrieve the entire list of 10 million and then perform a calculation to get the latest entry? Or will the calculation be performed in the database first, then the 1 record will be sent to f#

Comment: If you are only getting `TOP 1` record in F# query, than that should generally translate to fetching just `TOP 1` record in SQL. The keyword here is _in general_ - this is the way it should work in most situations, but there may be cases where it does not work as great as you'd hope. I think it is reasonable to trust the system in most cases, but it's useful to have some diagnostics around to double-check things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# query expressions are quite smart. I don't exactly understand how they work besides that they use quotations (similar to `System.Linq.Expressions`) to convert code to SQL. ORMs have [measurable overhead](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper#performance), raw queries would be faster, but they're able to produce optimised queries

Given these models and ef-core context

```ml
[<CLIMutable>] type Address = { Id: int; City: string; Country: string }
[<CLIMutable>] type Person = { Id: int; Name: string; Age: int; Address: Address }

type PeopleContext() =
    inherit DbContext()

    [<FSharp.Core.DefaultValue>]
    val mutable _people : DbSet<Person>

    member db.People
        with get () = db._people
        and set value = db._people <- value

    override _.OnConfiguring options =
        options.UseSqlite("Data source=db.db3") |> ignore
```

I've created this query

```ml
query {
    for person in ctx.People do
        where (person.Age > 21)
        select person.Address.City
        take 1
} |> Seq.toArray |> printfn "%A"
```

That got translated to this sql

```sql
SELECT "a"."City"
FROM (
    SELECT "p"."AddressId"
    FROM "People" AS "p"
    WHERE "p"."Age" > 21
    LIMIT @__p_0
) AS "t"
```